# How to write a process that restart again every time that it's killed

Tags: linux, shell, process, background-process

I want the exact opposite of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158194/kill-a-process-that-keeps-restarting). I want to know how I can create a process that keeps restarting if it's killed. Could someone give me an implementation example?

**For instance**, let's assume that I have a simple process that continuously logs a timestamp and an incrementing counter to a log file, like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILE_PATH "/home/lincoln/date.log"

int main() {

    time_t current_time;
    struct tm *time_info;
    int counter = 0;

    while (1) {
        FILE *file = fopen(FILE_PATH, "a");
        if (file == NULL){
          perror("Failed to open the file");
          return 1;
        }
        // Get the current timestamp
        time(&current_time);
        time_info = localtime(&current_time);

        // Format the timestamp
        char timestamp[25];
        strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time_info);

        // Write timestamp and counter to the file
        fprintf(file, "%s | Counter: %d\n", timestamp, counter++);
        fflush(file);

        fclose(file);
        sleep(5); // Sleep for 5 seconds
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To generate the binary (ELF file), I used the following command:

```
gcc logger_file.c -o date_test
```

(Please note that this is just an example. It could be a "hello world" program that keeps printing. I chose logging because I want to observe the effects of it continuously running.)

From the [quoted question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158194/kill-a-process-that-keeps-restarting) (correct me if I'm wrong), it's achieved by a parent process that monitors the child process. If the child process is killed, the parent process restarts it. I understand this concept, but I don't know how it's implemented in practice.

Could someone demonstrate how it can be implemented using the provided binary example?
(link references to me study more about are wellcome too.)

Please let me know if more information is needed.

**EDIT:** In my implementation, I'm planning to do it on an embedded device. Basically, in my working environment, I have **sysVinit** as the startup system and **BusyBox v1.23.2** as the toolset on a 3.18.44 kernel running on a armv7 processor (I'm using `gcc-12-arm-linux-gnueabi-base` toolchain).

Comment: confused now. Are you interested into how to write a supervisor, or interested in how to use the supervisor from your init system?

Comment: @MarcusMüller From the beginning, I didn't realize that it was possible to use the supervisor of my init system. In your question, you mentioned systemd, and for me, this wasn't useful. However, with your instructions, I achieved success in writing my supervisor (with just some changes in your code). Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've provieded more information because I thought that with maximum information, it would be more useful for others to help me find a solution to my problem. The problem is that I have a binary app, and I want it to run continuously/ "forever" without anything stopping it. (That's the main point of embedded applications, right? Haha.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're lucky enough to be on a system which has a regular `init` daemon, you can run that process out of the `/etc/inittab`, where you can specify that the process is to be restarted if it dies.

In `/etc/inittab` you add an entry like this:

```
dtst:345:respawn:/path/to/date_time
```

The `dtst` is just a label; `345` means this is active in run levels 3, 4 and 5, and `respawn` means that the process will be restarted if it dies (what we want).

Then use the `telinit` command, or `kill -HUP 1` to tell `init` to re-read the file.

There is probably some complicated way to do something similar on systems that use `systemd` instead of `init`.

BusyBox `init` ignores the `runlevels` field in the `inittab` entry; the `id` field has some special meaning; if it isn't blank, it sets the controlling TTY.

Another way is to have a "nanny" shell script which does this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  /path/to/date_test
done
```

We could have it so that the loop will terminate if the program terminates normally with a successful status:

```
while !/path/to/date_test; do : ; done
```

While the `date_test` program terminates unsuccessfully or abnormally, run the do-nothing null command `:` and repeat.

The shell which runs this loop is itself not protected from termination, though; this is useful if the program is unreliable and crashes, requiring restarts.

Comment: as explained in my answer, the systemd init process can do the same, but you do get actual control. In all honesty, "old" init systems are not "luck" to have when you need to supervise daemons. Systemd allows for much finer control over how, when to and under which circumstances not to restart a service. (fully agreeing that what you write is appropriate according to OP's plans)

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution solves my problem in an incredibly elegant way. I just have one question about the label in inittab. Are there any naming restrictions? Does it need to be short? Because I tried naming the label as "testing" and it didn't work, but it worked with "test"! Could you please provide me with some reference links? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

A process can't revive itself once it's dead. It's dead, it literally cannot do anything anymore (that's the point).

You can have a supervisor that checks the state of a process and spawns a new process when the old one died.

Almost all (but a few niche or slim-container-oriented) Linux distros make that trivial: systemd can do that, and all you need to do is write a systemd service unit file and set the [`Restart=` property](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) to `always`, or `on-abnormal`, or `on-abort`. That's it!

Then, systemd acts as the supervisor (no need to write your own supervisor that fiddles with procfs or similar), and things work out of the box, and you can still *explicitly* stop the service from restarting through `systemctl`.

Now, you asked how this would be done in practice. I alluded to `procfs`; that's one of the ways: you just watch the /proc/{PID} directory or e.g. the memory maps in there.

However, and that's how supervisors *usually* do it (and systemd's service.c does it like that), is that they register a handler for `SIGCHLD`: When the child of a process exits, the parent process gets a signal. Because the supervisor is actually starting the supervised process as child through `fork`, that works.

So, you need roughly the following [loosely lifted from an ancient Oracle Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-4750/signals-7/index.html) and Linux man-pages `man waitpid`:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void proc_exit() {
  int wstat;
  pid_t pid;

  while (1) {
    int retval = waitpid(pid, &wstat, WNOHANG);
    if (retval == 0)
      return;
    else if (retval == -1)
      return;
    else
      printf("Return code: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstat));
  }
}
int main() {
  signal(SIGCHLD, proc_exit);
  switch (fork()) {
  case -1:
    perror("main: fork");
    exit(0);
  case 0:
    printf("I'm alive (temporarily)\n");
    exit(42);
  default:
    pause();
  }
}
```

The child process sees `fork` return 0, so it's the process that prints `"I'm alive…`. Here, you would, if you wanted to spawn a different executable (i.e., your supervised process) call `execve`.